# Restore OneNote Ribbon from backup

Tags: backup, restore, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote, ribbon

I made a full system backup (drive image) of my machine, then re-installed everything. I went from Windows 7 Home-Premium to Professional.

I can't figure out what files I need to restore from the backup to get my OneNote ribbon back to the way it was before.  I had it heavily customized since I basically live out of OneNote (tablet pc).

I couldn't find anything useful on Google or on microsoft's site. I don't want to restore the entire backup just to use the ribbon exporter... that would take hours!  I was able to restore tags and stuff by just restoring a couple of .dat files. I was hoping it would be that easy for the ribbon.

Does anyone know what files I need to restore to get my ribbon back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question.

An esoteric Google search lead me to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704589.aspx

The documentation discusses where the UI files are stored. It mentions the directory

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Office
```

and files with the extension:

```
.officeUI
```

So I restored the one named "OneNote.officeUI" from the backup and it seemed to work!